# retrieving multiple firebase objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i'm working on a web app. Basically I've gotten the following code to work but how do I remove each employee it fetches when the remove button is clicked? Also can I use how do I make the list updated when a child is removed. For example, right now if I add a child the table automatically updates it with the new child without refreshing the page.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Balkar/Employees");
rootRef.on('child_added', snap => {
  var id = snap.child("ID").val();
  var name = snap.child("Name").val();
  var email = snap.child("Email").val();

  $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + name + "</td> <td>" + email +
                          "</td><td><button>Remove</button></td></tr>");
});

<h1>All Employees</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Employee ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
      <tbody id="table_body"></tbody>
    </table>
```

EDIT:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Balkar/Employees");

rootRef.on('child_added', snap => {
  var id = snap.child("ID").val();
  var key = snap.key;
  var name = snap.child("Name").val();
  var email = snap.child("Email").val();
  var btn = "<button id='removeEmployee' class='mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent'>Remove</button>";

  $("#table_body").append("<tr id='"+key+"'><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + name + "</td> <td>" + email +
                          "</td><td><button>" + btn + "</button></td></tr>");

  $("#removeEmployee").click(
    function(){
      rootRef.on('child_removed', snap => {
        var key = snap.key;
        $('#'+key).remove();
      });
    }
  );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the list when an item is removed, listen for `child_removed` events and find the item by its **key**:

```
rootRef.on('child_added', snap => {
  var id = snap.child("ID").val();
  var key = snap.key;
  var name = snap.child("Name").val();
  var email = snap.child("Email").val();

  $("#table_body").append("<tr id='"+key+"'><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + name + "</td> <td>" + email +
                          "</td><td><button>Remove</button></td></tr>");
  });
});
rootRef.on('child_removed', snap => {
  var key = snap.key;
  $('#'+key).remove();
});
```

Comment: i updated the code above under edit but nothing happens when i click the remove button

Comment: I only provided the code for the Firebase side of things. For handling button clicks, you should be able to get somewhere with these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+button+click+handler

Comment: but i think the on click event listener in ok its something with my firebase code, nah?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are creating multiple remove buttons with same id. That should not be the case. Second, you need to associate the key with each button so that when user clicks on one of them you know which item to remove. Following code should help.

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Balkar/Employees");

rootRef.on('child_added', snap => {
  var id = snap.child("ID").val();
  var key = snap.key;
  var name = snap.child("Name").val();
  var email = snap.child("Email").val();
  var btn = "<button key='"+ key +"' class='removeEmployee mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent'>Remove</button>";

  $("#table_body").append("<tr id='"+key+"'><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + name + "</td> <td>" + email +
                          "</td><td>" + btn + "</td></tr>");

});

// now this click handler can be (should be) moved outside 'child_added' callback
  $('#table_body').on('click', ".removeEmployee", function(){ // note: using 'removeElement' as class, not as id
    var key = $(this).attr('key');
    var itemToRemove = rootRef.child(key);
    itemToRemove.remove()
   .then(function() { // removed from Firebase DB
     console.log("Remove succeeded.")
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
     console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
   });

  });
// keeping this separate so that even if the item is removed by any other means (e.g.- directly from server console) this UI will remain in sync
rootRef.on('child_removed', function(snap) {
  var key = snap.key;
  $('#'+key).remove();
});
```

ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#remove

Comment: it seems like the remove part isn't working. because it doesn't even fetch any employees anymore but when i comment out the remove part it works.

Comment: There was a typo. It was `itemToRemove.remove()..then`. Remove the extra dot and plz try again.

Comment: uhm it loads the data now but it doesn't remove the object when the button is clicked. i added an alert to see if the function works when button clicked. it doesn't

Comment: My bad. I didn't have a firebase project to test the code yesterday. Try this code now. Its working for me.